# Ignoring Local git Config file

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am on Windows and have my diff and merge tools set in my global git configuration file. Most of my project are in Visual Studio. Some of the projects, I work with have a local config files in .git directory. I think this is created when visual studio creates a repo. The issue is VS overrides my diff tools and merge tools with vsdiffmerge.exe. In my global settings it is set to as beyond compare. Is there a way I can tell git to give precedence to my global config instead of local config. I always use git on command line and expect beyond compare to open when I type "git difftool". It is fine while doing a diff in VS to open vsdiffmerge.

Comment: not really.... that's the point of having a global and a repo config file. Repo will override the global one no matter what (to the best of my knowledge). You are dealing with a VS problem, not a git problem

Comment: Try `git -c diff.tool=<NameOfYourDiffTool> difftool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global Git configuration file on Windows for the logged-on user is located in the folder `C:\users\<username>\`, named `.gitconfig`. All you need to do is to ensure that the global Git config file contains the difftool you want to use by default--and ensure that it's NOT listed in the local Git config file (which is located in your solution folder's .git folder under the file name `config`).

Your local Git `config` file typically has two `[difftool]` entries: one to specify whether to prompt you for which difftool to use and the other to configure a particular difftool. It might look something like this:

```
[difftool]
    prompt = true
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" //t
    keepBackup = false
```

Just copy to the clipboard those entries from the local Git config file then delete them (**first back up your config file!**). After that, open the global Git file and paste those entries there (or modify any existing `[difftool]` entries, as needed).

At that point, your command-line `Git difftool` command will invoke the globally configured difftool rather than the locally defined one.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed difftool section from local, Probably I have to do this every time I clone?

Comment: Edit the config file on a version you will want to clone, if that's the case.